# Finding and updating an object, returning the whole object, recursively

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, state

I have been trying my hand at recursion, it seems I can get close to what I am expecting however, I am stuck at returning the whole object after an update.

Lets say for an example you have an object with an array that contains the keys to where you would like to update a value...

```js
const testObj = {
    data: {
        dataNested: {
            dataNestedNested: "Hello",
            amITrue: false
        }
    },
    data2: {
        dataNested2: {
            dataNestedNested2: "Hello",
            amITrue2: false
        }
    },
    data3: {
        dataNested3: {
            dataNestedNested3: "Hello",
            amITrue3: false
        }
    }
}

const scopeArray = ["data2", "dataNested2", "dataNestedNested2"]
```

How would you return the object as a whole *after* updating the target key/value. Here is what I have built...

```js
    const findAndUpdate = (obj, array, key, i, value) => {
      if (i === array.length - 1) {
        obj = { ...obj, [key]: value };
        console.log(obj);
      } else {
        i++;
        findAndUpdate(obj[key], array, array[i], i, value);
      }
    };
    findAndUpdate(testObj, scopeArray, scopeArray[0], 0, "World");
```

that `console.log` outputs

```
> {dataNestedNested2: "World", amITrue2: false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear if you want to return an updated version of the whole `testObject` or of the inner object `{dataNestedNested2: "Hello", amITrue2: false}}`.  If it's the former, I have a [function I use often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20setPath), `setPath`, which -- although with a slightly different signature -- seems to do exactly what you want.

```js
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const testObj = {data: {dataNested: {dataNestedNested: "Hello", amITrue: false}}, data2: {dataNested2: {dataNestedNested2: "Hello", amITrue2: false}}, data3: {dataNested3: {dataNestedNested3: "Hello", amITrue3: false}}}
const scopeArray = ['data2', 'dataNested2', 'dataNestedNested2']

console .log (setPath (scopeArray) ('World') (testObj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The signature is structured the way I prefer to work: fully curried with the values more likely to change coming after those less likely to change.  But if you want a single call that passes the object, the scope path, then the value, like this: `findAndUpdate (testObj, scopeArray, 'World')`, we could either wrap this:

```
const findAndUpdate = (obj, array, val) =>
  setPath (array) (val) (obj)
```

or rewrite it

```
const findAndUpdate = (o, [p, ...ps], v) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: findAndUpdate ((o || {}) [p], ps, v)}
  )
```

Comment: I know you are supposed to use the comments to ask for clarification, but I am going to go against that and personally thank you. 

That is a beautiful function that works flawlessly. Thank you sir, you deserve a raise.

Comment: Glad you like it.  Somehow, I lost a long paragraph of explanation.  If I find time soon, I'll come back and add it again.  And about that raise... do you know my boss?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

iterate over keys and reduce object.

```js
const testObj = { data: { dataNested: { dataNestedNested: "Hello", amITrue: false } }, data2: { dataNested2: { dataNestedNested2: "Hello", amITrue2: false } }, data3: { dataNested3: { dataNestedNested3: "Hello", amITrue3: false } } }
const scopeArray = ["data2", "dataNested2", "dataNestedNested2"]

function findAndUpdate(object, keys, value) {
    const lastKey = keys.pop();
    let mod = keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object);
    mod[lastKey] = value;
    return mod;
}

let value = findAndUpdate(testObj, scopeArray, "World");
console.log(value);
```